# ML Classification - Decision Boundary Algorithm

Tags: machine-learning, classification

Given a classification problem in Machine Learning the hypothesis is described as below.

```
hθ(x)=g(θ'x)
z = θ'x
g(z) = 1 / (1+e^−z)
```

In order to get our discrete 0 or 1 classification, we can translate the output of the hypothesis function as follows:

```
hθ(x)≥0.5→y=1
hθ(x)<0.5→y=0
```

The way our logistic function g behaves is that when its input is greater than or equal to zero, its output is greater than or equal to 0.5:

```
g(z)≥0.5
whenz≥0
```

Remember.

```
z=0,e0=1⇒g(z)=1/2
z→∞,e−∞→0⇒g(z)=1
z→−∞,e∞→∞⇒g(z)=0
```

So if our input to g is θTX, then that means:

```
hθ(x)=g(θTx)≥0.5
whenθTx≥0
```

From these statements we can now say:

```
θ'x≥0⇒y=1
θ'x<0⇒y=0
```

If The decision boundary is the line that separates the area where y = 0 and where y = 1 and is created by our hypothesis function:

What part of this relates to the Decision Boundary?  Or where does the Decision Boundary algorithm come from?

Comment: This is pretty standard stuff from Andrew Ng's course.  h is the hypothesis, ' means transpose, I didn't want to write it out to muddy the algorithm.  The algorithm above is a sigmoid function to predict positive (1) or negative (0).  The context is clearly stated in the title of trying to figure out the algorithm for a Decision Boundary within a Classification problem in ML.

Comment: Terrific. Just add a reference to this notation and I'm sure someone can help you. It sounds like a basic ML question, but devoid of necessary context.

Comment: I'm not sure what further context you're looking for.  It's stated that this is in the context of a Classification Problem for ML.  That I want to know where the algorithm to compute the decision boundary in the Classification context comes from.  Aside from answering the question myself I'm not sure what else you want.

Comment: @Lizzard math never has a pretty standard notation or anything. I totally agree with Heath. Andrew Ng might use this notation but most others won't. It's hard as well to read such expressions in plain text.

Comment: I understand, I have read Introduction to Statistical Learning and taken Andrew Ng's introductory course and they used the same notation.  Maybe it's just a coincidence.  Also, doing a quick google search of the terms shows the same or similar notation.  Beyond that hypothesis is a very common term in ML.  Math may not have a standard notation but maybe in the context of ML it does, one can hope.  In any event I posted the same question on a different board and got a couple quick responses you can see below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Courtesy of other posters on a different tech forum.

Solving for theta'*x >= 0 and theta'*x<0 gives the decision boundary. The RHS of the inequality ( i.e. 0) comes from the sigmoid function.

Theta gives you the hypothesis that best fits the training set.

From theta, you can compute the decision boundary - it is the locus of points where (X * theta) = 0, or equivalently where g(X * theta) = 0.5.

Answer (score 1):

This is basic logistic regression with a threshold. So your `theta' * x` is just the vector notation of your weight vector multiplied by your input. If you put that into the logistic function which outputs a value between 0 and 1 exclusively, you'll threshold that value at 0.5. So if it's equal and above this, you'll treat it as a positive sample and as a negative one otherwise.

The classification algorithm is just that simple. The training is a bit more complicated and the goal of it is the find a weight vector `theta` which satisfies the condition to correctly classify all your labeled data...or at least as much as possible. The way to do this is to minimize a cost function which measures the difference between the output of your function and the expected label. You can do this using gradient descent. I guess, Andrew Ng is teaching this.

**Edit:** Your classification algorithm is `g(theta'x)>=0.5` and `g(theta'x)<0.5`, so a basic step function.